# Counting total number of only subfolders in a specific layer with Powershell

Tags: powershell, count, command, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

**Hello lovely helpers** :-)

I'm looking for a powershell-command who can give me the total amount of subfolders on the 3rd level on every folder on a specific drive - the letter for the drive is X:

**So for example let's say X has these folders:**

X:\FolderX1\FolderX2\FolderX3\FolderX4

AND

X:\FolderY1\FolderY2\FolderY3\FolderY4\FolderY5

**So on layer 3 there are 3 folders in this example** - FolderX4, FolderY4 and FolderY5

The X-drive has hundreds of folders, with many subfolder in them, so i would like powershell to count it for me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like `(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\*\*\*' -Directory -Recurse).Count`

Comment: Hello Theo, thanks for the line - i'm getting a much larger number than expected though.
Are you sure this is only for the 3rd level and not 3rd level plus level 1 and 2?

Thanks in advance